# Is it necessary to test every assumptions for each predictor in a MLR?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, predictive-models, modeling, linear-model

If I have a dataset with several potential predictors and I want to perform a multiple regression model, do I have to test every assumption (normality of residuals, linear assosiation, homoscedasticity) for each predictor? Or I have to check just the final model (including checking the independece of the predictors)?

Is it possible that a predictor don't meet the assumptions individually, but that it be significant with all variables?

Comment: The assumptions are for the model as a whole, not for each predictor. The assumptions you mention, however, are common but not required for every application of linear regression. In particular, the Gauss-Markov theorem that gives the conditions where the coefficient estimate is unbiased and has minimum variance (BLUE), requires neither normal residuals nor uncorrelated predictors; those are useful for going inference into the coefficients. What is the goal of your regression?

Comment: @Dave I've two main goals:

1)Make a model that predict the response variable
2)Inference on the individual impact of each predictor in the response variable